# Can we update the description text for duplicate questions (again)?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I just noticed that apparantly the text that is added in the question-closed box for duplicate questions has changed recently.

Here's what I've seen on an old duplicate question:

[image]

Here's what it says on a newer duplicate:

[image]

I wasn't usually paying much attention to the exact wording until recently, but now I must say, I liked the older version much better. In contrast to the newer text, the older one mentions the possibility to reopen, i.e., edit to point out the difference for justifying to keep both questions around. Which is in my opinion the preferable option vs. posting a new almost identical but slightly differentiated question.

Was this changed deliberately?

**Does the text need a clarification? I think the description should make it very clear that editing the question might make it eligible to reopening. Especially new users might otherwise be unaware of this possibility.**

**Example:** (someone with native-speaker-skills might express this better)

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different in order to make it eligible for reopening.

While I was thinking about what reasons there may be for suggesting the user to ask a new question instead, nothing really came to my mind. So I left that part out of this example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's [tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Besides asking about the difference in the messages, I also suggested to point out the possibility for a closed question to be reopened in the description. I think this would provide or explain the motivation for editing the question to the OP. Or should I rather post a separate question for the proposal of this change?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That makes no sense whatsoever. If you ask about anything which was designed intentionally on meta, it's off topic now?

Comment: I edited my question to highlight the main point I had in mind with this feature request, which is not addressed by the only answer so far.

Answer (score 31):

There are two different messages. If you are viewing **your own** question which is closed as a duplicate, the message will suggest that you attempt to edit it before trying to ask a new question. Anyone else viewing the question will not see the blurb about editing.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. Now I need to think about whether I consider that a bug or a feature. Do you know of a way to review the descriptions from "both perspectives" for other close reasons as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's ok to answer here with my doubts, or it would be better to risk on duplicating with a new question.

The only answer here says there are 2 different messages, but in my short time here I saw just one of them.

I recently flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661332/float-point-addition-why-this-works-everytime) as a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659746/addition-of-floating-point-why-the-first-code-work) from the same user one hour ago, and added a comment pointing the OP to edit his original question.
A bit later it was set as duplicate. However, from the template used (see screenshot)

[image: Screenshot: Duplicate]

I have doubts on the goal of this action.

I cannot use yet this tool, so I wonder if it is easy to wrongly chose a template. And anyway I think a lot times it could be preferable an edit to the original (duplicated) question instead of asking again the same (a bit rephrased), so if I were to chose I would prefer a third template that suggest only editing the original (duplicated) question.