# Can we have dynamic description texts for duplicate questions based on the target age?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, close-reasons, canonical

In a comment to [this canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572), @jib stated:

> This is a duplicate of [another] already asked question, yet […] the **old question [is marked] as a duplicate of [the] new question**. Isn't that hijacking? Stackoverflow's boilerplate on the old question now gives the wrong chronology, saying "*This question has been asked before and already has an answer.*" when the answer it points to is in fact newer. I think the attribution needs to go the other way.

I think he's quite right, this sounds wrong.

Can we make the text displayed there dynamic, based on the relative age of the question posts? If the duplicate target is younger than the closed question, the text should say

> This question has been asked elsewhere and has a better answer there. If that answer does not [… (etc.)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284958/1048572).

Comment: The box at the top of the question is already dynamic and could benefit from displaying a custom message in this case. The close reason itself should be tweaked so that it covers all the cases for which duplicate closure can be used (right now it also makes cases where the duplicate has no answers really confusing). We have to remember that the duplicate reason doesn't only appear in that close notice, but also in the close dialog, mobile site, and the mobile apps. Coding in special checks seems rather wasteful when we could just improve the reason itself.

Comment: @animuson: I didn't think [having no answers was possible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165928/183280)?

Comment: @Bergi Pretty sure, on main sites, it's only if both questions are posted by the same user. Otherwise it does need an answer.

Comment: @Kendra Ah I didn't know the details of those conditions.

Comment: @Bergi The rule also doesn't apply on Meta.